# Excel Combine Rows with Partially Filled Columns

Tags: excel, merge, rows

Would anyone be able to assist me with the following table?

| Name | Apple | Pear | Banana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Yes |  |  |
| Bob |  | Yes |  |
| Alice |  | Yes |  |
| Alice |  |  | Yes |
| John |  |  |  |

The goal is to have the all these rows merge/join and fill in all empty columns if the unique name is present. See below for the end goal.

| Name | Apple | Pear | Banana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Yes | Yes |  |
| Alice |  | Yes | Yes |
| John |  |  |  |

Please note that I am restricted in terms of using only Excel (2016) with no ability to add add-ons.

**Much appreciated!**

Comment: Have you considered using a pivot table?

Comment: I suggest you develop a VBA or Power Query solution, both of which are available in Excel 2016.  Post your code if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually easily in 3 steps:

1. Replace all "Yes" values with number 1
2. Inside "Data" tab, [Consolidate data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b)
3. Replace all number 1 with "Yes"

Take a look at the video:

[image]

And probably you can record a macro with this for sure and make it instantly.